# Return the largest group of Anagrams

Tags: java, arrays, file, anagram

This method should return the largest group of anagrams in the input array of words, in no particular order.  It should return an empty array if there are no anagrams in the input array.  This method must call the methods I created that checks if the strings are anagrams method an insertionSort method with a new Comparator class or lambda expression. For some reason when getLargestAnagramGroup gets called on the small array with no anagrams, I fail. I was wondering if I could get some assistance. Thanks!

```
/**
     * @param largestStr a string array.
     * @return the largest group of anagrams in the input array of words, in no
     *         particular order. It returns an empty array if there are no anagrams
     *         in the input array.
     */
    public static String[] getLargestAnagramGroup(String[] largestStr) {
        if (largestStr.length == 0) {
            return largestStr;
        }

        // creating the new array
        String[] duplicate = new String[largestStr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < duplicate.length; i++) {
            duplicate[i] = largestStr[i];
        }

        // puts everything to lower case and sorts them out
        for (int i = 0; i < duplicate.length; i++) {
            duplicate[i] = (String) sort(duplicate[i].toLowerCase());
        }

        // creates a comparator
        class compareStrings implements Comparator<String> {
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        }
        compareStrings compString = new compareStrings();

        // sorts the list to alphabetical order
        insertionSort(duplicate, compString);

        // temporary array to hold how many instances of each anagram
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // compares to each other
        String compare = duplicate[0];

        // keeps track of the anagram
        int totalValues = 0;

        // for loop for how many anagrams there are and adds them up
        for (int i = 0; i < duplicate.length; i++) {
            if (duplicate[i].equals(compare)) {
                totalValues++;
            } else {
                temp.add(totalValues);
                compare = duplicate[i];
                totalValues = 1;
            }
        }

        // adds the last value to the list
        temp.add(totalValues);

        int largestNumber = temp.get(0);

        // gets the largest number in the array
        for (int i = 1; i < temp.size(); i++) {
            if (temp.get(i) > largestNumber) {
                largestNumber = temp.get(i);
            }
        }

        // will find the correct anagram in the array
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= temp.indexOf(largestNumber); i++) {
            sum += temp.get(i);
        }

        String value = duplicate[sum - 1];
        String[] largetsAnagram = new String[largestNumber];

        // count keeps track of the new list values
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < largestStr.length; i++) {
            if (areAnagrams(largestStr[i], value)) {
                largetsAnagram[count] = largestStr[i];
                count++;
            }
        }
        return largetsAnagram;
    }
```

Comment: How does it fail, what should happen at that place instead? It's currently too much code to debug-by-reading especially when you don't know what to look for

Comment: I have a file in the package named sample_word_list.txt and this is the output I get "sample_word_list.txt (No such file or directory) Empty list
[Ljava.lang.String;@5f205aa"

Comment: If your list of words has no anagrams, then the largest group of anagrams is of size 1, namely of any word in the list.

Comment: you have an issue with "no such file" and the code you show contains nothing about files so I guess there's an issue in the code that deals with files. Could simply be that you put the file in the wrong place. The current directory for a java programs is not in the source folders, it's the project root, so if you load a file without specifying a path it wouldn't look for a file inside your source packages. It's different if you use resources. Can update your question to you show the code / provide details about your file handling?